# Can Vuetify autocomplete have two arrays?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

There are two empty data array fruits and animals. When the user clicks `v-autocomplete` the search bar will show fruit data `["apple","banana","kiwi"]` as a list. When the user types something the fruit data will be disappear and show the animal data from the API instead. So basically there are two data arrays, but I can add only one item to the Vuetify autocomplete.

```
 <v-autocomplete 
  v-model="select" 
:items="fruits" 
:search-input.sync="search">
```

So is there any way that I can change the items array after user type something in input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your fruit array with the search results from your API.

Let's say you have an array called `items` that will hold all of the results and an array called `fruit` for only the fruit. Then when you component is created you could add everything in `fruit` to `items`, e.g. `this.items = [...this.fruit]`.

Then when you do a search and you get the results back and put it in an array called `results`, you can set `items` to contain everything in `results` plus everything in `fruit`, e.g.

```
this.items = [...this.fruit, ...this.results]
```

Vuetify seems to still apply it's own search function after you return your search results so it will still filter out `fruit` that don't match your search query.

You can check out a demo I made on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/asdasgqq/pen/MWYqEKv?editable=true&editors=101).